# perl6: html color gradient generator

Tags: html, raku

**Edit**: The comments have been incorporated to [this module](https://github.com/mimosinnet/P6-Color-RangeToColor/blob/master/lib/Color/GradientGenerator.rakumod) in GitHub. The final code has been included at the end of this thread. Thanks very much for the detailed and brilliant suggestions.

---

Inspired in this [color gradient generator](http://www.herethere.net/%7Esamson/php/color_gradient/), this is a gradient generator in perl6. I wonder if the code could be simplified or improved. It converts the hex colour to base10, calculates the gradient colours, and then converts the colour to base16.

```
my $initial_color = '#FF0000';
my $final_color   = '#00FF00';
my $gradient      = 10;

my @initial   = ($initial_color ~~ /\#(..)(..)(..)/).list.map: { .Str.parse-base(16) };
my @final     = ($final_color   ~~ /\#(..)(..)(..)/).list.map: { .Str.parse-base(16) };
my @range     = @final Z- @initial; 
my @increment = @range.map: { $_ / $gradient };

my @color;
@color.push: @initial;
for (1..$gradient) -> $i {
  @color.push: @(@color[$i-1]) Z+ @increment;
}

for (0..$gradient) -> $i {
  @color[$i] = '#' ~ ( @(@color[$i]).map: { .base(16,0).fmt('%02s') } ).join;
}

my $fh = open '/tmp/delete.html', :w;
for (0..$gradient) -> $i {
  $fh.print: "<span style='background-color:@color[$i]'>&nbsp;</span>"; 
}
$fh.print: '&nbsp';
$fh.close;

run <elinks -dump -dump-color-mode 3 /tmp/borrem.html>;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to limit my initial answer to not include modules, but I'll also cover a module that can help out some here too later.

```perl
my $initial_color = '#FF0000';
my $final_color   = '#00FF00';
```

While there's nothing wrong with using underscores, the tendency in Perl 6 has been to move towards hyphens, which would give us `$initial-color` and `$final-color`.

```
my @initial   = ($initial_color ~~ /\#(..)(..)(..)/).list.map: { .Str.parse-base(16) };
```

This is a bit of personal preference, I'd write this as

```
my @initial = .map: *.Str.parse-base(16) with $initial-color ~~ /\#(..)(..)(..)/;
```

Since it allows you to get rid of most of the parentheses/braces.  Note that in any case, you don't need the `.list` because your `Match` is already an `Iterable`.  But this is of course a pure matter of taste (some might prefer parentheses around the `.map` to emphasize it's separate from the `with` postfix.

You can also prestore the regex, particularly if you plan on using it more often:

```perl
my $hex-format = /\#(..)(..)(..)/;
my @initial = .map: *.Str.parse-base(16) with $initial-color ~~ $hex-format;
```

Your next two lines have two different techniques for applying math operators across lists:

```
my @range     = @final Z- @initial; 
my @increment = @range.map: { $_ / $gradient };
```

You could use a zip operator for both ( `@range Z/ ($gradient xx 3)` ), or you could opt for a hyper meta operator:

```
my @range     = @final «-» @initial;
my @increment = @range «/» $gradient
```

Now for generating the colors themselves, you had

```
my @color;
@color.push: @initial;
for (1..$gradient) -> $i {
  @color.push: @(@color[$i-1]) Z+ @increment;
}

for (0..$gradient) -> $i {
  @color[$i] = '#' ~ ( @(@color[$i]).map: { .base(16,0).fmt('%02s') } ).join;
}
```

First the easy things.  If I see a variable `@color`, I assume it is a single entity with multiple constituent entities (one color, three values — R, G, B).  But in this case, it's a list of colors, so the variable name is best used in plural.  Also, you don't need parentheses around the list for the for loop.  Just `for 0..$gradient -> $i` works.

Your first for loop uses the previous item to determine the next one, so you have a push outside the loop.  There's a few ways to solve this.  If you have to do an initial step like that, I like to put it in the loop using `FIRST` (or `once`, both are functionally equivalent here).

```perl
my @color;
for 1..$gradient -> $i {
  FIRST @color.push(@initial);
  @color.push: @(@color[$i-1]) Z+ @increment;
}
```

But we can actually rewrite this to calculate the value without relying upon the previous entry:

```perl
my @color;
for 0..$gradient -> $step {
  @color.push: @initial «+» @increment «*» $step;
}
```

This could be even further reduced into a one liner, but I don't think that's necessary nor desirable here.  What's great here about the hyper operators is that they read like scalar arithmetic (`$initial + $increment * $step`) so readability is maintained.

Your second loop can also be simplified quite a bit by just looping on the values.  I think it makes most sense to just put them into a new array

```perl
my @html-colors;
for @colors -> @color {
  @html-colors.push: '#' ~ @color.map( *.base(16,0).fmt: '%02s' ).join;
}
```

Anytime, though, you have a `.map` that has another method chain in its code block, you have a candidate for a hyper method call `».`

```perl
my @html-colors;
for @colors -> @color {
  @html-colors.push: '#' ~ @color».base(16,0)».fmt('%02s').join;
}
```

Basically, `».foo` means *take every element and `.foo` it*, and it returns a list of the values, which can be `».bar` on every element.  Note that `.join` doesn't have the hyperoperator, because we want to act on the resulting list.

But you could also loop in a rw manner (notice the `<->`) with

```perl
for @colors <-> @color {
  @colors = '#' ~ @color».base(16,0)».fmt('%02s').join;
}
```

Because now both loops though are `0 .. $gradient`, it might make sense to merge them:

```perl
my @colors
for 0..$gradient -> $step {
  my @intermediate = @initial »+» @increment »*» $step;
  @colors.push: '#' ~ @intermediate».base(16,0)».fmt('%02s').join;
}
```

Lastly when you print, remember you can just loop on the color items:

```
for @colors -> $color {
  $fh.print: "<span style='background-color:$color'>&nbsp;</span>"; 
}
```

Which also allows a one liner using the topic variable `$_` (and in this case, absent doing anything else, makes more sense to me):

```
$fh.print: "<span style='background-color:$_'>&nbsp;</span>" for @colors;
```

Since it's effectively the same loop, this is, of course, a candidate for putting back in the main loop, but there's something to be said for separating the calculations from the final output.

Rewritten, my version would be:

```perl
my $initial-color = '#FF0000';
my $final-color   = '#00FF00';
my $gradient      = 10;

my $hex-format = /\#(..)(..)(..)/;

my @initial = .map: *.Str.parse-base(16) with $initial-color ~~ $hex-format;
my @final   = .map: *.Str.parse-base(16) with   $final-color ~~ $hex-format;

my @increment = (@final »-» @initial) »/» $gradient;

my @colors;

for 0..$gradient -> $step {
  my @intermediate = @initial »+» @increment »*» $step;
  @colors.push: '#' ~ @intermediate».base(16,0)».fmt('%02s').join;
}

my $fh = open '/tmp/delete.html', :w;
$fh.print: "<span style='background-color:$_'>&nbsp;</span>" for @colors; 
$fh.print: '&nbsp';
$fh.close;
```

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas to improvement.

If I need `List of Str` I prefer `comb` to `match`.

```perl
my @initial   = $initial_color.comb(/<xdigit> ** 2/)».parse-base(16);
#or
my @final     = $final_color.substr(1).comb(2)».parse-base(16);
```

You can use the sequence operator `...` to make sequence of colors.

```perl
my @color =  @initial, { @^p Z+ @increment } ...  * ~~ @final;
```

Method `fmt` works with list and can convert to hex numbers.

```perl
@color .= map: '#' ~ *.fmt: '%02X', q{} ;
```

One more, I use `fmt` on `List` to make HTML color gradient.

```perl
my $html-color-gradient = @color.fmt( q{<span style='background-color:%s'>&nbsp;</span>}, q{}) ~ '&nbsp';
```

Last two steps in one by method `tree`.

```perl
my $html-color-gradient = @color.tree(
      *.fmt( q{<span style='background-color:%s'>&nbsp;</span>}, q{}) ~ '&nbsp',
      '#' ~ *.fmt( '%02X', q{} ),
  )
```

You could use `spurt` instead of `open, print, close`.

```perl
spurt '/tmp/delete.html', $html-color-gradient;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have learned a lot from these detailed and brilliant responses. This is the module I have built from your suggestions, and [this is the link](https://github.com/mimosinnet/P6-Color-RangeToColor/blob/master/lib/Color/GradientGenerator.rakumod) to the module in GitHub. Thanks very much!

```
unit module Color::GradientGenerator;

sub gradient_generator( Str :$initial-color = '#FF0000', Str :$final-color = '#00FF00', Int :$gradient = 10) is export(:gradient_generator) {

  # Transform Str HEX to Array (R,G,B)
  my @RGB-ini-color   = $initial-color.substr(1).comb(2)».parse-base(16);
  my @RGB-final-color = $final-color.substr(1).comb(2)».parse-base(16);
  my @RGB-range       = @RGB-final-color «-» @RGB-ini-color; 
  my @RGB-increment   = @RGB-range «/» $gradient;

  # RGB gradient: inicial-color, range from (initial-color + increment) TO (watever matches final-color)
  my @RGB-gradient    = @RGB-ini-color, { @^a «+» @RGB-increment } ... (* ~~ @RGB-final-color);

  # Return (R,G,B) to HEX 
  return @RGB-gradient.map: '#' ~ *.fmt: '%02X', q{} ;
}
```